# Recommendation for Messaging Server for Chat Room

Tags: xmpp, chat, mqtt

Need some recommendation for a Instant Messenger/Chatroom Application for web/mobile.

MQTT seems to fit the bill in terms of reliability. However Chat room principles involve the following challenges.

1. User is subscribed to ONE room/topic at the time.
2. User in a chatroom can block one or more participants in the room preventing them for reading any messages that the User types.
3. Administrator can KICK a User out of the chatroom or throw him to another room (Lobby for example).
4. Messages have to be intercepted for spam checks/content modified to render smileys and other codes based on what messaging pack the User might have purchased. Complete control over the message content.

With these in mind is writing a NodeJS socket server an ideal solution or MQTT with plugin code is a way to go?

Is MQTT even a right fit for the requirement? Need some inputs.

Answer (score 1):

This strikes me as a primarily opinion based question, but I'll take a crack at it.

Certainly you can do this... if you look on Github there are several projects (For example: https://github.com/happiestcoder/mqtt-chat) that achieve something similar. MQTT is lightweight and I find it a joy to work with--and understand--in comparison to other protocols so if you want to, go for it! I'm all for more people using MQTT!

But it does seem like the consensus is that MQTT is more useful for low-bandwidth M2M than instant messaging / chatting. A better alternative is XMPP. (Which is mentioned in your title, so maybe there is confusion here?) XMPP offers quite a few features--most notably better identity tracking--and extensions that seem well suited to your use.

Here is a nice, simple discussion of the difference between the two protocols which i think will help you: https://servicelab.org/2015/05/08/xmpp-versus-mqtt-comparing-apples-with-pears/ . In summary, MQTT is simpler and far more efficient, but XMPP offers a more robust feature set at the cost of processor power and bandwidth. From my perspective XMPP is the clear winner for a chat room whereas MQTT is far superior for high-volume metric communication.